# Windows 8 Background Task Progress Handler Not Activating

Tags: c#, windows-8, background-process

I've written a background task in an Win 8 app I'm working on to periodically check for new items in feeds. The task works and if the app runs, successfully fires off it's completion handler. However, I cannot get the progression event handler to fire. I'm using a helper class to register the event/re-attach the handlers

```
    public static async void RegisterBackgroundTask(string taskName, string entryPoint, uint checkTime, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler completionMethod, BackgroundTaskProgressEventHandler progressHandler = null)
        {
            var backgroundAccessStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            if (backgroundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedMayUseActiveRealTimeConnectivity ||
                backgroundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedWithAlwaysOnRealTimeConnectivity)
            {
                foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
                {
                    if (task.Value.Name == taskName)
                    {
                        // Re-Register progress completion event handler.
                        task.Value.Completed += completionMethod;
                        task.Value.Progress += progressHandler;

                        return; // The task is already registered, so no need to set again.
                    }
                }...

The progress code:

private async void OnBackgroundTaskProgress(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task, BackgroundTaskProgressEventArgs e)
        {

            await dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    uint percentage = e.Progress;

                    Debug.WriteLine("Background task progress: " + e.Progress);

                    SubscriptionManager manager = (SubscriptionManager)App.Current.Resources["subManager"];

                    var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

                    if ((bool)localSettings.Values["currentlyCheckingPodcast"])
                    {
                        if (podcastUpdateStatus.Visibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed)
                        {
                            podcastUpdateStatus.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
                        }

                        podcastUpdateStausText.Text = (string)localSettings.Values["currentCheckName"] + " " + (int)localSettings.Values["checkNo"] + "/" + manager.Subscriptions.Count;
                    }

                    if (e.Progress == 100) { podcastUpdateStatus.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed; }
                });
        }
```

And my registration code:

```
BackgroundTaskHelpers.RegisterBackgroundTask("TileUpdater", "NarrowCastBackgroundTasks.TileUpdater", checkTimeuint, OnBackgroundTaskComplete, OnBackgroundTaskProgress);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was missing: the progress event handler is only fired when you set the progress property in the Background task's instance.